# Configuring ELK stack

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am learning to setup ELK stack.But no tutorial seems to work for me completely.
I tried to follow [this guide.](https://logz.io/learn/complete-guide-elk-stack) 
Is any error here.Can any one help.Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try to reach Kibana? Have you checked logs? You can find them under directory `/var/log/kibana/`.

Comment: showing no file or diretory

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem for above mentioned link. But i found another link and it work for me. Try [ELK stack](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-elastic-stack/).

Answer (score 0):

I went the same path, but at the end of the day the best resource to learn is:

[LOGSSTASH OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.x/index.html)
and [ELASTIC FORUM for logstash problems](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/logstash)

Answer (score -1):

Could you be more specific about the OS and versions you need? Can you use Docker?

There is a nice guide for Ubuntu [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)

If you are using Docker, try [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)

Comment: i am running on deb 9  and elk 6.4 for configuring.

Comment: The ubuntu guide should work then, give it a try. I would use Docker though, easier to clean or rebuild after your tests